# Will not stop looping

Tags: java, loops

Write a program that generates a random number (between 1 and 10) and asks the user to guess what the number is. If the user’s guess is higher than the random number, the program should display “Too high, try again.” If the user’s guess is lower than the random number, the program should display “Too low, try again.” The program should use a loop that repeats until the user correctly guesses the random number.

This is my code and when I run it, it will not stop looping and I have no idea why. Thank you!!

```
/////guess/////
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class guess
{
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int numberToGuess =rand.nextInt(10);
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    int guess;
    boolean win =false;
      while (win == false)

      System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 10");
      guess = input.nextInt();

      {
        if(guess == numberToGuess)


        win=true;
      }
       if(guess<numberToGuess)
       {

         System.out.println("Your guess is too low");
       }

       {
       if (guess > numberToGuess)

         System.out.println("Your guess is too high");
         System.out.println("You win!");
         System.out.println("The number was"  +numberToGuess);
       } 
  }
}
```

Comment: `while` loops and `if` statements require curly brackets to execute multiple statements.  E.g. `while (condition) { //do this code }`  Your code just falls straight through, that's why it loops forever.

Comment: @LukePark:  No, they don't *require* it, but you're not that far off as to why this code isn't working the way one would intend.

Comment: @Makoto they *do* require curly brackets if you want to execute multiple statements, as the OP is attempting to do.

Comment: @LukePark:  Yes, that's absolutely true.  However, you're making it sound like it's absolutely mandatory lest there be a syntax error, which isn't true.

Comment: Although the braces aren't cumpulsory. Without curly braces, the control statement applies only to the single statement that follows, in this case the System.out.println.

Comment: Another riddle that could be easily solved by proper code formatting ... (but only if OP would care about proper code formatting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't just apply to `while` statements; `if` and `for` statements are affected by this as well.

Your `while` statement will only ever execute the *next* line if it is not contained in a block.

```
// Without curly braces, the println is the only thing in the loop.
while (win == false)
    System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 10");
// This isn't part of the loop!
guess = input.nextInt();
```

You fix this by ensuring that everything you want to loop on is contained by curly braces:

```
while(!win) {
    // ALL of the logic you want to execute while win is false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have copied your code as is, have a look at your `while` loop you have no `{}`  so it will keep printing

```
System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 10");
```

until `win` changes, which in this code it won't.